# Don't get how to apply the intermediate value theorem here

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Note: I know how to prove this for $f(a) = f(a+100)$, but no clue how to do it for the value that's asked of me.

There's a continuous function $f(x): \mathbb R \to\ \mathbb R$

With these properties:

1. $f(x) ≤ 2 \ \text{for} \ x≥200$
2. $f(x) ≤ 1 \ \text{for} \ x≤100$
3. $f(x)=3 \ \text{for} \ x=150$

I'm supposed to show that there exists an $a$ for which the property $f(a)=(a+200)$ is true. I've tried applying the intermediate value theorem every which way, but at this point I don't know if that's the right way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g(y)=f(y+200)-f(y)$. Then $g$ is continuous. We have $g(-50)=f(150)-f(-50)=3-f(-50)\geq 3-1=2>0$. On the other hand, $g(150)=f(350)-f(150)\leq 2-3=-1<0$. Hence, there is  a point $a$ between $-50$ and $150$ where $g(a)=0$.